# How to get an external DVD drive to work?

Tags: windows-xp, dvd-burning

I've bought an external DVD reader (Samsung, USB Slim Portable Optical Drive). But, it couldn't read CDs/DVDs on my PC. When I tried in another PC, it's okay.

What's wrong with my PC? The OS is Windows XP SP2.

Comment: Did Windows recognise the drive when you first plugged it in?

Comment: Maybe not related, but why haven't you gone to SP3

Comment: @ChrisF : Yeah, windows detect the drive, something like E:/CD DVD Rom. But when I inserted the disc, it could't read.

Comment: @Col: I've been play with SP2 for along time comfortably. I though it doesn't matter. Anyway, I'll try to use SP3....

Answer (score 5):

Did you plug the reader into the **front** ports on your PC and does the reader have two USB connectors on the end of its cable? If so, try two ports on the **back** of the machine and see if it then works properly.

The issue is that many external optical readers/writers need to be plugged into two USB ports to help them get all the power they need to work properly - in other words, they need two USB ports'-worth of power, but due to the way some front panel USB connectors are wired up, they share a USB power feed so even using the two connectors on the drive's lead only gives you one lot of power.

Of course, this may not be the problem but I have seen exactly this situation on several brands of machine in our offices - the drives *seem* to be OK, but they won't recognise any media.

**Executive Summary:** Some external USB optical and disk drives don't work properly on a PC's front panel USB ports, but they will work fine when connected to ports on the back.

Comment: Yeah, I did. and the reader also has two USB connectors as well as on my PC. And i've been try to plug the reader on the front and back ports of my PC. But it still failed. Does it's caused by my OS? I've been reinstall my OS few days ago, and I think there is corrupt file when installing.

Comment: It's difficult to tell whether this could be OS or driver related but anything's worth trying if the front/back port issue hasn't helped.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just realized that I haven't try to plug the reader on the back ports of my PC. Hehehe... :-). Yesterday, I tried it works. Thank you Linker......I'll vote your answer.....

Comment: Cheers - a tick would be great too!